# GetMyTimeline in twitter via twitter api and twitter4j

Tags: android, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I want to see my timeline on my logcat, or other timeline with hard-coded username and password.
I'am using Twitter API and twitter4j as a library:
this is my current code:

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            configurationBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true);
            configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
            configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(SECRET_KEY);
            configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
            configurationBuilder
                    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
            configurationBuilder.setUseSSL(true);
            Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration)
                    .getInstance();
            try {
                List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
                Log.d(TAG, "Showing home timeline.");
                for (Status status : statuses) {
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            status.getUser().getName() + ":"
                                    + status.getText());
                }
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "TwitterException: " + e.toString());
            }
```

CONSUMER_KEY: is the Consumer key that i've got when i registered my app in dev.twitter.com
same for SECRET_KEY, ACCESS_TOKEN, and ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET.

**And this is my logcat output:**

```
07-24 06:29:16.027: D/FeedsActivity(1621): TwitterException: No authentication challenges found
07-24 06:29:16.027: D/FeedsActivity(1621): Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
07-24 06:29:16.027: D/FeedsActivity(1621):  http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=e5488403 or
07-24 06:29:16.027: D/FeedsActivity(1621):  http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0a0b625e
07-24 06:29:16.027: D/FeedsActivity(1621): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[e5488403-0a0b625e 6ece33f2-3760e528], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the code is clean and clear :)
i thought the problem would be a twitter-api settings.
And that was it.
I've recreate another application and maked sure to enable this:

```
 Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter
```

The poor Exception handling and  exlanation is the main issue here(TwitterException). it's not well documentated.